# In Windows file explorer, how to quickly jump to file based on MORE THAN ONE letter?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, hotkeys, user-interface

In windows file explorer, if I hit a letter like "r", I'll immediately jump to a file/folder beginning with the letter "r", which is quick and super convenient. But is there a way to do that with more than one letter? E.g. "ri" would jump me to a file starting with "ri". I ask because I have a zillion folders all starting with "r", and very often want to jump to a specific one that starts with "ri". Is there any quick way to do this? Or do I just have to use the search bar, or manually scroll to "ri" from "r"?

If I recall correctly, Ubuntu's file explorer supports this behavior completely.

Comment: Just quickly type "ri". It works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically provided the answer to your question.

You click a file, then you type. If you are fast enough, it will actually jump to the first occurence of those letters.

So ri would jump to the first folder or file that starts with ri. Do note, the delay is short, so first locate the keys and press them quickly.

The delay is about 3 to 4 seconds before it doesn't register it as a sequence anymore and goes to i instead of ri.

Comment: I am slapping myself for suffering for months without giving it an honest try @.@. Thank you. I will now go to a corner and ruminate on how much of an idiot I am >.<

Comment: Every single one of us once felt like an idiot before we were enlightened. ;) Its a trade of a master. :)